# forecast model has shifted result (lag = -1)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, lstm

I have a problem with the LSTM forecast model; it predicts the current value instead of the next value. I have checked the data alignment, and it is correct. Try with:

- different scallers and unscale the data
- different input window
- use the difference in Target Value (target.diff())

But with the same problem, I also checked the data; it is stationary, not a random walk.
the prediction result as shown figure
[image][image]